# String Reversal using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

**Problem**-To reverse a string using pointers,
but my code instead of printing reversed string ,is printing the first letter of the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char n[100];
    char *ptr;
    ptr = n;
    char a[100];
    char *sptr;
    sptr = a;
    scanf("%s", n);

    for(i=0;n[i]!=0;i++)//Calculating the size of the string
        for(;(*sptr=*(ptr+i))!='\0';sptr++,ptr--)
        {
            ;
        }
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "[c] string reversal" on this site will turn up a *substantial* number of hits. And no nested for loop is needed for this, so rethink your algorithm.

Comment: As it is you have a nested loop, i.e. the inner `for` loop which supposedly is meant to perform the reversal is nested within the loop calculating the string length. Is this intentional?

Comment: I am really not getting your program

Comment: No it is not intended to be nested,my approach was to just calculate length of the string using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a string using pointers in a function, output in main is garbled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810393/reverse-a-string-using-pointers-in-a-function-output-in-main-is-garbled)

Comment: There is a full working solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810412/1392132).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold.

First, you're missing a `;` after the first `for` loop.

```
for(i=0;n[i]!=0;i++); //note the ;
```

Secondly, you're array index used is out-of-bounds

```
for(;(*sptr=*(ptr+i))!='\0';sptr++,ptr--)
```

you need to reduce `i` once before using it.

you should write

```
for(;(*sptr=*(ptr+i-1))!='\0';sptr++,ptr--)
```

Note: IMHO, you're making a simple thing too complex. Think of an easier logic. There are many. for a *live* example, follow the link in the comments by Mr. WhozCraig.

Comment: Or [just do this](http://ideone.com/YljESF) and forget all the indexes. That's what the pointers are for.